# Is there a $apply operation n in FHIR service in Azure Health Data Services?

Tags: azure, interop, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

Is there a $apply-operation to apply a PlanDefinition to a patient so that we can get it as a CarePlan in FHIR service in Azure Health Data Services? I know there are other operations that are written in the azure documentation but I haven`t seen the $apply-operation.

Answer (score 0):

No but the CQF-Ruler if setup has some of the functionality - https://github.com/DBCG/cqf-ruler

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply